# how i can add title to my featured image?

Tags: post-thumbnails, get-the-title

I want to add a title to my featured image, how I can add this item:

```
$attr = array(
    'title' => 'howdy partner',
    'alt'   => 'a nice view of the ocean',
);

// pick one, note 2 or 3 arguments:
the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', $attr );

echo("<a href='$p->permalink'>". // null for current $post->ID (use within loop)
    get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'post-thumbnail', $attr ).
    "</a>");
```

my site is : https://abzarwp.com

Comment: what do you want as title?...the image name or post name??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but the below code is more correct.

```
$attr = array(
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'alt'   => 'a nice view of the ocean',
);

echo sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_the_permalink(), get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'post-thumbnail', $attr ) );
```